# XElement-like API for HTML creation for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, html

I'd like to encapsulate some HTML-creation logic (e.g. for eventual usage in an ASP.NET MVC razor page).  Can I do this with a structured API in plain C#?

I'd like to avoid error-prone string-based constructions where I manually need to build tags and escape the right strings since that strikes me as much harder to maintain and likely to result in html-injection vulnerabilities.  Something like the `XElement` API (for instance), but then for html generation: an API that takes care of well-formedness at minimum and avoids boilerplate.

Does such an API exist?  What's the best way to generate html fragments safely and easily?

Comment: Have you seen the `System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder` class in `System.Web.Mvc.dell `? This class is used by the [mvc html helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs).

Comment: See [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @nemesv: do you have an example?  that sounds like an answer... :-)

Comment: @L.B. I've got lot's of experience with HtmlAgilityPack and it's ill suited for this.  It's fairly buggy, quite slow and quite large.  It's also targeted for the (much more complicated) use of parsing messy html rather than generating clean html.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne I've expanded my comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built in HTML generator in ASP.NET MVC. It's called [TagBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.aspx) and it is used internally by all the [built in Html helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs).

For example generating the following HTML:

```
<div id="someId" class="someClass">
  <p class="paragraph">Some text</p>
  <input type="button" value="Click"/>
</div>
```

Looks like:

```
var div = new TagBuilder("div");
    div.GenerateId("someId");
    div.AddCssClass("someClass");
var p = new TagBuilder("p");
    p.AddCssClass("paragraph");
    p.SetInnerText("Some text"); //HtmlEncode the parameter
var button = new TagBuilder("input");
    button.MergeAttribute("type","button");
    button.MergeAttribute("value","click");

div.InnerHtml = (p.ToString() + button.ToString());
```

In our projects we usually create a thin fluid wrapper around the `TagBuilder` something like [this one](http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/Fluent-wrapper-for-ASPNET-MVC-TagBuilder.aspx) to make the it's API a little bit more fluid.

If it's ok to use some thrid party libraries and you need some advanced features you can have a look on:

- [MvcContrib.FluentHtml](http://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/mvcfluenthtml-fluent-html-interface-for-ms-mvc/) - Available on [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcContrib.FluentHtml)
- [HtmlTags.Fubu](http://htmltags.fubu-project.org/) - Available on [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlTags)